# Can't install zend debugger

Tags: php, apache, zend-debugger

I'm trying to install zend debugger in my Ubuntu 9.04 machine, I've done it in win. but not in linux, I hope you could help me, **this is what I've done**:

1)Copied the file ZendDebugger.so to /etc/php5/apache2 (didn't choose this folder for anything in special).

2)Added this lines to php.ini:

zend_extension="/etc/php5/apache2/ZendDebugger.so" zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1,127.0.1.1,localhost,*
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always

I've also tried without quotes(zend_extension=/etc/php5/apache2/ZendDebugger.so)

3)Copied file dummy.php to /var/www

And then restarted Apache but I didn't see the information about Zend Debugger in the phpinfo(), the only related thing I found there was report_zend_debug On.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Added this lines to php.ini" - did you edit the right php.ini? phpinfo() or echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path'); can tell you.

Answer (score 2):

I found much more easy to install [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) in my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I never tried Zend, but Xdebug works well with Netbeans on my Ubuntu 9.  Can't say as this answers the question, though!

Comment: I have to +1 this, even though it doesn't answer the question. Spent almost an hour trying to get Zend to work on Ubuntu 12.04 with Eclipse IDE, then decided to apt-get install php5-xdebug and added line xdebug.remote_enable=1 to /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini. Worked right away, total time 10 mins (including googling)...

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo mv /etc/php5/apache2/ZendDebugger.so /usr/lib/php5/20060613/ZendDebugger.so
```

This is where your `memcache.so`, `apc.so`, etc. are located. Unless you modified your php extensions directory that is where new exts should go.

In `php.ini`:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20060613/ZendDebugger.so
```

cd to that directory and `chmod a-x ZendDebugger.so` to remove executable bits from the `.so`.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

In another terminal window, `tail -f /var/log/error.log` and clear console so it is easy to see new log entries coming in (cmd-k on macos).

Then:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

If there are no errors in `error.log`, check `phpinfo()` and see if the debugger section shows up.

You might get errors in the configuration of other php extensions that occur further up in `php.ini` (e.g., xcache or eaccellerator) that will make loading stuff further down in `php.ini` problematic.

This is a baseline setup and should work if there are no other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to install [Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/downloads)
You'll get Zend Debugger enabled by default, along with some other nice features. There is a link to the deb repository available through the download page.

Comment: This is easy way. Nobody wants to install 2 additional products to be able to configure something.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same steps that you did with the same result. In the end the problem was that I was trying to load a 32bit binary with apache running in 64bit mode base (as described in this [post](http://www.entropy.ch/phpbb2/viewtopic.php?t=2905)) I was able to get it running immediately by doing the following.

1. stopping apache
2. executing  `sudo arch -i386 /usr/sbin/httpd`
3. restarting apache.

After replacing the 32bit binary with the 64bit binary everything worked as expected with no special apache handling. There was also some facepalming involved, but it did not affect the overall outcome.

Comment: How did you replace the "32bit binary with the 64bit binary"

Comment: Originally I had downloaded the 32bit version of the Zend Debugger, so I went back and downloaded the 64bit version of the debugger and overwrote the ZendDebugger.so I had placed there previously.